# Upon loading new AJAX, Isotope container does not target new objects but overlaps old objects instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope

So all the content on my page is loaded from an AJAX call.

I thought that if I simply put my isotope in a document ready function it would work but it does NOT work:

```js
$(function(){

        container = $('#content');
        container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.tile',
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
            },          
          });

    });
```

The AJAX call succeeds but nothing appears and the page remains blank. Any idea why? I get no errors.

I did however manage to get my isotope to work by using the jquery .then method after making my AJAX call. Here is an example where Isotope works:

```js
function grabNews(){

    var $content = $('#content');

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'json/dummy.json',
        success: function(news) {

        for(i=min; i<max; i++){
                $content.append('<div class="tile x150x100"><h3>' + news[i].headline +'</h3><br>' + news[i].text + '</div>')
                }
        }
        max=max+50;
        min=min+50; 
        },
        error: function () { alert('Loading Failed...'); 
        }
    }).then(function(){
        container = $('#content');
        container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.tile',
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
            },          
          });
    });
}
```

```css
.background {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tile {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.x300x300 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.x300x200 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}
.x200x200 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.x150x100 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;   
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="content" class="background">

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

So using the .then method works UNTIL I scroll to the bottom of the screen and make another AJAX call to load more content. The new content does not enter the Isotope container. It is simply ignored.

I did find a quasi solution to my problem by inserting:

```js
$('#content').isotope('destroy');
```

Into

```js
.then(function(){
        $('#content').isotope('destroy');
        container = $('#content');
        container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.tile',
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
            },          
          });
    });
```

I put it in my jquery .then function and the isotope container updates and recognizes new objects. So success! BUT then my browser scrolls back to the top! Why?

How can I scroll down and update my isotope container while making ajax calls?

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a brief example to implement the isotope js work upon the ajax call and append to your isotop container.

first add the live CDN for isotop js:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

lets assume we have the div with class lets say, "isotop": For Example:

```
    <div class="isotop">
        ................
    </div>
```

Now there may be some content inside this isotop div with class lets say, "isotop-item": For example:

```
    <div class="isotop">
        <div class="isotop-item">
            <p>Item 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="isotop-item">
            <p>Item 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="isotop-item">
            <p>Item 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also we have a button on which if clicked then the content should be loaded inside isotop div. For example:

```
    <div class="btn_load">
        <a href="btn btn-info">Load More</a>
    </div>
```

Now if you want to append the content that you get from ajax call then it is as simple as you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn_load').on('click',function(){
            var $grid = $('.isotop').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.isotop-item',
            });
            $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo site_url('Items/addMoreItems'); ?>',
                type : 'post',
                data : 'offset='+offset,
                success: function(res){
                    var $items = $(res);
                        $grid.append($items)
                        .isotope('appended',$items);
                    }
               });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: The res in success must be:

```
    <div class="isotop-item">
        <p>Item 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="isotop-item">
        <p>Item 4</p>
    </div>
```

And for sure you will get the isotop content will all of the isotop properties.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved already I assume.

Anyway you can tell isotope about your new items in the AJAX succes callback, see [isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended) under functions -> appended

Answer (score 0):

Update for

## Wordpress, Vue, Internet Explorer 11

*Example has lazyload code added.*

I just found out an alternative fix: I created a canvas element with the correct sizes instead of only loading and placing the images. This canvas is used as a placeholder for ratio calculations. The images sit with position absolute on top.

Caveat: you need to know the image sizes/ratio. In my wordpress case they are embedded in the json call.

It even works with Internet Explorer 11.

```
<figure>
    <canvas 
      :width="post.image.sizes['medium-width']"
      :height="post.image.sizes['medium-height']"
    ></canvas>
    <img
      class="lazyload"
      :src="post.image.sizes.thumbnail"
      :data-src="post.image.sizes.medium"
      :alt="post.image.alt"
      :width="post.image.sizes['medium-width']"
      :height="post.image.sizes['medium-height']"
    >
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure,canvas { position: relative; }
img { position: absolute; top:0; left:0;  }
```